# How can we fill the select tag of html with json result in partialViews in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

How can we fill the select tag of html with json result in partialViews in asp.net MVC?

Does anyone have any links that you can supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good example of one way to fill a dropdown with a JSON result using jQuery:

[http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813151408/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx)

Comment: Its Working on List But not on Collection even after i have made changes in .js file.
Any Special Reason.